# react native preload all the image in listview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an image card listview on a page and it loads only certain a number of images until user scroll to bottom. When scroll it the last item. It start load rest of images.

Is there some way to preload all the images in the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you can try to use [`prefetch`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/image.html#prefetch) to download and cache the images in advanced or play with the different rendering parameters of ListView (for instance [`pageSize`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/listview.html#pagesize) or [`initialPageSize`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/listview.html#initiallistsize).